# ROS Kinetic - catkin_make install fails

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS Kinetic. To learn more, I have been going through the tutorials provided by the ROS website (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)  and have been doing fine up until creating  [a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). At the final step where one needs to remake the `catkin_ws` package with  the command `catkin_make install`, I am given the following output on the terminal:

```
allen@allen-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make install
Base path: /home/allen/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/allen/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/allen/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/allen/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/allen/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/allen/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/allen/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src
####
#### Running command: "make install -j1 -l1" in "/home/allen/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/allen/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/allen/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- beginner_tutorials: 1 messages, 1 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/allen/catkin_ws/src
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/_setup_util.py
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:54 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/home/allen/catkin_ws/src/catkin_generated/installspace/_setup_util.py" to
  "/usr/local/_setup_util.py".


Makefile:61: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
Invoking "make install -j1 -l1" failed
```

I don't understand why the  `...installspace/_setup_util.py` file can't be copied. I didn't do anything with the file. I have looked at the `cmake_install.cmake` lines of code that result in the error and see nothing wrong:

```
54  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "/usr/local" TYPE PROGRAM FILES                                      
      "/home/allen/catkin_ws/src/catkin_generated/installspace/_setup_util.py")
55   endif()
56
57   if(NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT OR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}" STREQUAL "Unspecified")
58        list(APPEND CMAKE_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES
59        "/usr/local/env.sh")
60        if(CMAKE_WARN_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION)
61             message(WARNING "ABSOLUTE path INSTALL DESTINATION : ${CMAKE_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES}")
62        endif()
```

I have been dealing with this issue for over a week and have not found any solutions throughout the internet. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Windows 10 laptop using Oracle VM Virtualbox.If somebody can help solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263120/ros-kinetic---catkin_make-install-fails/) by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file cannot be copied because your install space is `/usr/local` only users with roo permissions can copy in that directory.

The problem here is that catkin_make is trying to install your package to `/usr/local` instead of
`Install space: /home/allen/catkin_ws/install`.

Can you try the following commands in a new terminal and comment here with the outcome?:

1. Open a new terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
2. `cd /home/allen/catkin_ws`
3. `rm -rf build devel install`
4. `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
5. `catkin_make install`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2017-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on 2017-06-03**:
I don't know why, but I was unable to submit my full response as a comment. I had reached the "maximum characters for a comment". Thus, I placed my reply to your suggestion as an answer. I hope the output is useful.

**Comment by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on 2017-06-08**:
Are you able to still help?

**Comment by [Allen Ayala](https://answers.ros.org/users/30618/allen-ayala/) on 2017-06-11**:
I have fixed the issue! I had some Make files within my .src folder in catkin_ws that were not supposed to be there. Once I had deleted them, I rebuilt catkin_ws with catkin_make and later catkin_make install. Everything was built correctly and my issue was gone.